# How to correctly send multiple files and params with Koush / Ion

Tags: php, android, rest, android-ion, ion-koush

I'm using [Koush / Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) library.

I'm trying to send a request with regular parameters and files, like an html multipart form, but seems that don't send anything. Are this the correct way? or i'm doing it a bit weird?

When the request goes with files it takes more time to run the callback, so I think that is sending the files but in an incorrect way :/

Excuse me for the language, hope that I explained well.

The `print_r` for `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_FILES` always returns empty arrays.

```
Builders.Any.B builder = Ion.with(context).load(http_verb, route).setLogging(TAG, Log.ERROR);

Log.d(TAG, parameters.size() + " parameters and " + files.size() + " files");

List<Part> parts = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "File " + i + ": " + files.get(i).getName());
    parts.add(new FilePart("file_" + i, files.get(i)));
}

for(ApiParameter parameter : parameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Parameter: " + parameter.key + " = " + parameter.value);
    parts.add(new StringPart(parameter.key, parameter.value));
}

builder.addMultipartParts(parts);

builder.asString().setCallback(callback);
```

The Android log says this (cropped):

```
D/API: Request: PUT: http://api.<replaced>
D/API: 11 parameters and 1 files
D/API: File 0: f83ee728-8b1b-4cbf-8f6c-c103456366c4
D/API: Parameter: token = d81db04cc03faa16717a61eb494969b16e134b38
D/API: Parameter: id_google_place = EiJDYXJyZXIgQmFydHJpbmEsIFRlcnJhc3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue:

I can't post files in PUT (only with post), and I solved it with this:

```
    if(http_verb.toUpperCase().equals("POST")){
        for (ApiParameter parameter : parameters) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Parameter: " + parameter.key + " = " + parameter.value);
            builder.setMultipartParameter(parameter.key, parameter.value);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File " + i + ": " + files.get(i).getName());
            builder.setMultipartFile("file_" + i, files.get(i));
        }
    }else{
        for(ApiParameter parameter : parameters) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Parameter" + parameter.key + " = " + parameter.value);
            builder.setBodyParameter(parameter.key, parameter.value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: IF your back-end is on PHP, can you post the PHP code too?  @emmgfx

Comment: @Sp4Rx unfortunately I don't have access to the code. Sorry.